# cant sort collection in a descending fashion

Tags: javascript, sorting, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I am trying to sort my collection using `.sort()` however I can only seem to sort the collection in an ascending manner, by code for the collection is like this,

```
    var ProjectCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    url: '/projects',
    model: app.Project,
    sort_key: "finish_date",

    comparator: function (item) {
        return item.get(this.sort_key);
    },

    sortByField: function(fieldName, orderType) {
        console.log(fieldName, orderType);
        this.sort_key = fieldName;
        if(orderType == "acsending") {
            this.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
        } else if(orderType == "descending") {
            this.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
        }
    }

});
```

The sortByField function gets fired from the view on a select menu change, and it fires this function,

```
sortCollection: function(e) {

        this.collection.sortByField($('.sort').val(), $('.order').val());
        console.log(this.collection);

    }
```

Why would I not be able to sort in a descending order? The parameters that get sent to the collections function are correct, and the if and if else are run correctly based on those params.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `sortBy()` method instead of `sort()`.

As explained in the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-sort), `sort()` method just re-sorts the collection (as it does every time when a new model is inserted) and emits 'sort' event.

`sortBy()` method accepts the function Comparator that will define the order (as in your example) ([documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy)). Consider that instead of writing

```
function(a, b){return a-b}
```

you should write something like this

```
function(a, b){return a.get("field")-b.get("field")}
```

This way you compare objects's fields instead of the result of object's `toValue()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your models aren't sorted in a descending order because `sort()` does not accept the comparator callback (see sortBy() in the docs)

You need to put your logic in the `comperator()` - see this example: http://jsbin.com/petetiwiqo/1/edit?html,js,output